# Invoke UI function/command in cypress on a specific element

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a map (canvas) based application and on this element `voyage-ol-map`, I want to run invoke/run the `$0.centerOn([0,0], true)` function/command.

**It's how I do it in UI - dev tools:**

I locate the element in the *'Devtools: Elements'* tab and then in *'Devtools: Console'* I run `$0.centerOn([0,0], true)` which will make the map center-aligned (forces the map to be center-aligned from default view).

In Cypress, I tried this in order to make a visual capture but need some help as it is not working.

```
cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
      .invoke('centerOn([0,0], true)');
```

**Tried below also:**

```
cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
      .invoke('0.centerOn([0,0], true)');
cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
      .invoke('$0.centerOn([0,0], true)');
```

**Error in TR:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Using this

```
cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
 .invoke('centerOn', [0, 0], true);
```

gives the below error.

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.invoke() errored because the property: centerOn does not exist on your subject.

cy.invoke() waited for the specified property centerOn to exist, but it never did.

If you do not expect the property centerOn to exist, then add an assertion such as:

cy.wrap({ foo: 'bar' }).its('quux').should('not.exist')Learn more
cypress/pages/mapLayer_page.js:200:8
 
  199 |     cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
> 200 |       .invoke('centerOn', [0, 0], true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `centerOn` is a method added by some 3rd party library to the DOM elements. It is not a standard DOM method, and it is not a standard jQuery method. Thus you probably need to call it on the "pure" original DOM element, while `cy.get` yields a jQuery object. Here is how I would write it

```js
cy.get('voyage-ol-map')
  // ensure there is a single element
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .then($map => {
     // get the DOM node using [0] notation
     // and call the method
     $map[0].centerOn([0,0], true)
   })
```

Comment: Thank you @gleb,. I tried and it did not throw any error, at the same time it did not center the map as well. When I try to perform manually in Test Runner, I am getting `$0.centerOn([0,0],true)
VM2039:1 Uncaught TypeError: $0.centerOn is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:4` error

Comment: Please give me a repo with a reproducible example (app and test code) otherwise I do not know what it is doing there

Comment: Ahh well, the code works and I was using test data that already centered the map so could not identify the above fucntionality earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You generally pass the parameters to `.invoke()` separately, simple example [Function with Arguments](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Function-with-Arguments)

```js
cy.wrap({ sum: fn })
  .invoke('sum', 2, 4, 6)
```

But from the pattern of successful calling in devtools (`$0.centerOn([0,0], true)`), it looks like the function is attached to the element so `invoke()` won't work here.

If the test executes before function is attached, check it exists (with retry) before executing.

```js
cy.get('voyage-ol-map', { timeout: 10000 })
  .its('0')                             // unwrap element from jQuery 
  .should('have.property', 'centerOn')  // retries, in case function is late arriving
                                        // subject changes from element to function
                                        // so next line can just execute it
  .then(centerOn => centerOn([0,0], true))
```

If you get a fail on the `.should()`, then it's possible you have the wrong element.

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting the error and have updated the question with the same

Comment: From Gleb's answer, perhaps the function is not attached when the test attempts to call it. Adding a `.should()` to check it exists (may need to increase timeout on `cy.get('voyage-ol-map')`)